# Starting threads, logics for this type of functionality?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a logical problem i am not sure how to solve.. Basically i have a program that starts threads based on a numericUpDown value, if the user selects 5 in the numericUpDown box 5 threads will start.

The problem is that the user also has a listbox they can fill in with info, which will be used in the threads..

So what i want to be able to do in my loop instead of looping it 5 times from the numericUpDown value is if; lets say the user enteres 10 items in the listBox, and selects to use 5 threads.. i then want all the listBox items to be queued but only have 5 run at a time..

How would i accomplish this?

Oh if it matters this is how i start my threads:

```
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => doTask(numeret));
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you wish to use a `ThreadPool`, as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

You need to specify the number of threads to use, and then use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to queue your tasks.

Alternatively, you can use the parallel extensions to LinQ to perform asynchronous tasks (not the same as multithreading) - and specify the .MaxDegreesOfParalallism() value (which only sets the upper maximum)

```
itemsToProcess.AsParallel().MaxDegreesOfParalallism(numThreads).ForAll(item =>
{
    doTask(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, something like this is done using *worker threads*. You create a list of work items (= your listbox entries):

```
List<WorkItem> myWorkItems = ...; // contains 10 items
```

And you create your threads. You do not, however, assign a work item to the thread yet (as you do in your example):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {   // creates 5 threads
    var t = new Thread(doWork);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}
```

Each thread runs a loop, checking for new work items (thread-safe!) and doing work, until no more work is to be done:

```
void doWork() {
    while (true) {
        WorkItem item;

        lock(someSharedLockObject) {
            if (myWorkItems.Count == 0)
                break; // no more work to be done
            item = myWorkItems[0];
            myWorkItems.Remove(item);
        }

        doTask(item);
    }
}
```

---

This is similar to what the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) of the .net Framework does. The ThreadPool, however, is designed to work best when the number of threads can be chosen be the Framework. The example above gives you full control over the number of threads (which seems to be what you want).

Comment: As soon as you have more work items than you do CPU cores your performance will tank.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Why do you think so? The OP specifically *wants* to run X threads (independent of the number of CPU cores).

Comment: It doesn't matter what the OP *wants* to do; if you have more threads running (and CPU bound) than CPU cores you run into contention and increase context switching, drastically reducing performance of your threads and the rest of the system.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: I agree, this can happen (although it depends on the exact implementation of doWork -- if it contains a lot of external waits, for example, database access, then having more threads then CPU cores can *improve* performance). Nevertheless, the OP asked how he can start X threads to work on Y items, and I told him how to do that. So, if that was the reason for the downvote, I do ask you to reconsider.

Comment: The effects of having more ready threads than cores will not automatically 'drastically reduce performance'.  The rate of context-switching flattens off and, once [ready threads = twice no. of cores], cannot increase any further even if there are 1000 ready threads.  The performance hit generated by each context-switch is highly dependent on the scope of addressed data and so how much cache may need to be flushed/reloaded.  If each thread is just performing some complex algorithm on a small set of local data, performance with 8 threads is roughly the same as with 280 threads.

Answer (score 0):

Store the info from the listbox in a stack (for example).
Then, in the doTask() method : pop an element from the stack, do the stuff and do it again until the stack is empty.

Basically :

```
//Stack containing the info to process
Stack<string> infos = new Stack<string>();

//Method for the thread
void doTask()
{
    while(true)
    {
        string info;
        //Threadsafe access to the stack
        lock (infos.SyncRoot)
        {
            //Exit the thread if no longer info to process
            if (infos.Count == 0) return;

            info = infos.Pop();
        }
        //Do the actual stuff on the info
        __DoStuff(info);
    }
}
```